# Visual studio stops responding when I try to create solution

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, crash, solution

I recently built a new PC with windows 7 about a month ago, everything has been working fine until I tried to install Visual Studio today. First I tried 2013 community edition, it seemed to install fine, I restarted my PC as recommended, but when I tried to create a win32 console application for c++, the program stops responding. After several tries I decided to try 2012 express for desktop, as that was what I used on my old pc (also windows 7), however same issue, I cannot figure out why VS does not want me to create a project, and it's not even just C++, I can't create any kind of project/solution with any of their languages (basic, c#, etc). I have yet to find anyone else online with a similar situation, so I don't suppose anyone here can help me?

Comment: Did you try uninstalling completely and reinstalling?

Comment: @JonathanPotter Yes, as well as the "repair" option

Comment: Also ensure you have latest patches applied and Windows updates applied

Comment: You should also remove the SDL and codeblocks issue and make that a new question.

Comment: @Zammalad Just removed them, and I do have all the patches and updates

Comment: Have you tried doing running the following command in the visual studio command prompt - "devenv /setup" - This will take anything up to 15 minutes or so while the installation reparses templates etc.

Comment: Another route to go down would be collecting some log. Ensure VS is closed then run the command "devenv /log" in visual studio command prompt. Launch VS and try to create a project. Logs can be found %APPDATA%\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio<version>\ActivityLog.xml or %APPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio<version>\ActivityLog.xml (Win8)